How to achieve Quarkus non-blocking http reactive messaging
New to Quarkus and Reactive
Creating a reactive application in quarkus with request-reply model
Resource/Controller recevie the request with it's context and send the request to desired context channel. Here Resource to unblock the HTTP thread by Future or UNI.  Consumer listening for the channel to listen the request and apply operation and send response to response channel. Now Resource Future/Uni need to get the response and return response to user
Below are code samples
Resource
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyCustomResource {
 private static final ConcurrentHashMap<String, CompletableFuture<Response>> responseMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
 @Inject
 private MyCustomConfig MyCustomConfig;
 @Inject
 @Channel("request-channel")
 Emitter<RequestPayload> requestEmitter;
 @POST
 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 @Path("/{contextName}/MyCustom")
 public Uni<Response> submitRequest(@PathParam("contextName") String contextName, RequestPayload payload) {
     String requestId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
     payload.setRequestId(requestId);
     payload.setInstanceId(MyCustomConfig.apiInstance());
     MyCustomConfig.ContextConfig contextConfig = getContextByName(contextName);
     if (contextConfig == null) {
         return Uni.createFrom().item(Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).entity("Context not found: " +contextName).build());
     }
     String targetQueueName = contextConfig.requestQueueName() != null ? contextConfig.requestQueueName() : MyCustomConfig.requestQueueName();
     CompletableFuture<Response> responseFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
     responseMap.put(requestId, responseFuture);
     OutgoingRabbitMQMetadata metadata = OutgoingRabbitMQMetadata.builder()
             .withRoutingKey(targetQueueName).withCorrelationId(requestId).build();
     Message<RequestPayload> message = Message.of(payload).withMetadata(Collections.singleton(metadata));
     return Uni.createFrom().item(() -> {
         requestEmitter.send(message);
         return "Request sent successfully";
     }).flatMap(v -> Uni.createFrom().completionStage(responseFuture)).ifNoItem().after(Duration.ofMillis(contextConfig.responseWaitTimeoutMS()))
     .failWith(() -> new RuntimeException("Response timeout for requestId: " + requestId));
 }
 private MyCustomConfig.ContextConfig getContextByName(String name) {
     return MyCustomConfig.contexts().stream().filter(ctx -> ctx.name().equals(name)).findFirst().orElse(null);
 }
 @Incoming("response-channel")
 public void onResponseMessage(ResponsePayload response) {
     String correlationId = response.getRequestId();
     CompletableFuture<Response> futureResponse = responseMap.remove(correlationId);
     futureResponse.complete(Response.ok(response).build());
 }
}

Consumer
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyCustomConsumer {
    @Inject
    MyCustomConfig MyCustomConfig;  
    @Inject
    @Channel("response-channel")
    Emitter<ResponsePayload> responseEmitter;
    @Incoming("request-channel")
    public void onMessage(Message<RequestPayload> message) {
        RequestPayload request = message.getPayload();
        String responseText = request.toString() + ", Processed Successfully";  
        ResponsePayload respPayload = new ResponsePayload();
        respPayload.setRequestId(request.getRequestId());
        respPayload.setResponse(responseText);
        OutgoingRabbitMQMetadata metadata = OutgoingRabbitMQMetadata.builder()
                .withRoutingKey(request.getInstanceId()).withCorrelationId(request.getRequestId()).build();
        Message<ResponsePayload> responseMessage = Message.of(respPayload).addMetadata(metadata);
        responseEmitter.send(responseMessage);
    }
}

application.properties
mp.messaging.outgoing.response-channel.connector=smallrye-rabbitmq
mp.messaging.outgoing.response-channel.host=localhost
mp.messaging.outgoing.response-channel.port=5672
mp.messaging.outgoing.response-channel.username=guest
mp.messaging.outgoing.response-channel.password=guest
mp.messaging.outgoing.response-channel.address=valueadd_response
mp.messaging.outgoing.response-channel.concurrency=1

mp.messaging.incoming.request-channel.connector=smallrye-rabbitmq
mp.messaging.incoming.request-channel.host=localhost
mp.messaging.incoming.request-channel.port=5672
mp.messaging.incoming.request-channel.username=guest
mp.messaging.incoming.request-channel.password=guest
mp.messaging.incoming.request-channel.address=valueadd_request
mp.messaging.incoming.request-channel.concurrency=1

Facing issue as below
 Suppressed: io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.providers.wiring.TooManyDownstreamCandidatesException: 'Emitter{channel:'response-channel'}' supports a single downstream consumer, but found 2: [SubscriberMethod{method:'onResponseMessage', incoming:'response-channel'}, OutgoingConnector{channel:'response-channel', attribute:'mp.messaging.outgoing.response-channel'}]. You may want to enable broadcast using '@Broadcast' on the injected emitter field.
                at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.providers.wiring.Wiring$EmitterComponent.validate(Wiring.java:577)
                at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.providers.wiring.Graph.<init>(Graph.java:67)
                at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.providers.wiring.Wiring.resolve(Wiring.java:211)
                at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.providers.wiring.Wiring_ClientProxy.resolve(Unknown Source)
                at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.providers.extension.MediatorManager.start(MediatorManager.java:253)
                ... 21 more
        Suppressed: io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.providers.wiring.TooManyUpstreamCandidatesException: 'SubscriberMethod{method:'onMessage', incoming:'request-channel'}' supports a single upstream producer, but found 2: [Emitter{channel:'request-channel'}, IncomingConnector{channel:'request-channel', attribute:'mp.messaging.incoming.request-channel' , concurrency:'1'}]. You may want to add the '@Merge' annotation on the method.
                at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.providers.wiring.Wiring$SubscriberMediatorComponent.validate(Wiring.java:773)
                at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.providers.wiring.Wiring$ConcurrentComponent.validate(Wiring.java:970)
                at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.providers.wiring.Graph.<init>(Graph.java:67)
                at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.providers.wiring.Wiring.resolve(Wiring.java:211)
                at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.providers.wiring.Wiring_ClientProxy.resolve(Unknown Source)
                at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.providers.extension.MediatorManager.start(MediatorManager.java:253)
                ... 21 more


I'm not so expertise on messaging, but https://quarkus.io/guides/messaging#multiple-outgoings-and-broadcast may help
